# Wordpress login not working with PHP within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a site at http://raiter.fi/ but when i try to login to the admin panel it displays the entire wp-login code instead of the dashboard. I have done some investigation on this and it seems that PHP script written within JavaScript tends not to be working. Could this be a problem with my host or ...

Any suggestion would be appreciated. 
Also note that I have tried to rename the plugin folder,  also renamed the active theme folder and also used a fresh wp-login.php file but no success...

Thanks

Comment: you have probably deleted a php tag somewhere, but we cant see the result

Comment: Error establishing database

Comment: Well..Buddy..It seems that your database is missing from your WordPress site..! Have you recently moved your site to another host???

Comment: I would suggest to confirm your database details in your `wp-config.php` file present in your wordpress root directory..!

Comment: it seems i have mistakenly changed some details in the wp-config file...i will fix that as soon as possible

Comment: hey guys I have fixed the database error...but any suggestion about the original problem?

Comment: Never mind guys...All I needed was an upgrade of WordPress. thanks